# Typescript parent class method return type change by child property

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Is there a way to make the method used by the parent of a class return the accurate type (when the property it is using to derive the type is changed)?

Example:

```
abstract class A {
  a: string

  constructor(a: string) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}


class B extends A {
  b: string

  constructor(a: string, b: string) {
    super(a);
    this.b = b;
  }
}


abstract class AColl {
  abstract itemsMap: Map<string, A>

  items() {
    return [...this.itemsMap.values()];
  }
}

class BColl extends AColl {
  itemsMap: Map<string, B>
}

const bColl = new BColl();

bColl.items() -> Map<string, A> instead of Map<string,B>
```

In this example Intellisense thinks this is Map<string, A> instead of Map<string,B>, which I can get though I thought it would be able to derive the correct type (maybe naive on my end).

Is there a way to achieve this without having to re-implement the method on the child class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just parameterize the base class:

```
abstract class AColl<V extends A = A> {
    itemsMap: Map<string, V>; // no need to be abstract when class'es type param is used.

    items(): V[] {
        return [...this.itemsMap.values()];
    }
}

class BColl extends AColl<B> {
    // no need to have itemsMap field - extends AColl<B> does the job.
}

const bColl = new BColl();
bColl.items()
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. (Just started experimenting with Typescript so didn't know the parameterizing thing - will look into that a bit more)

Comment: Relevant documentation link: [generic classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the body of `AColl`'s `items` method, the type of

```
[...this.itemsMap.values()]
```

is *eagerly* evaluated to be `Array<A>`.  When you start looking up properties on `this`, the compiler substitutes `A` for `this`.  Such eager substitution is generally helpful, since it yields specific types for things, and otherwise the compiler would have to defer evaluation of just about anything on the off chance that someone cares about subclasses with more specific typings.  And such deferred types tend to be hard to use; the compiler cannot often verify assignability to them.

In your case, however, `this.itemsMap` evaluates to type `Map<string, A>` and your hopes are dashed; all subclasses of `AColl` will return `Array<A>` for `items()`.

---

Instead what you want is for `this` to be treated as "whatever `this` happens to be in whatever subclass of `AColl` is calling this method".  Such a concept already exists in TypeScript: "[polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)"; you can just use `this` as a type.

You can think of polymorphic `this` as a sort of "implicit generic type parameter".  That is, you could achieve a similar effect by making `AColl` *generic* like `AColl<T>` and then referring to `T` later.  Sometimes explicit generics might be the way to proceed (and I see the other answer here does that), but they are not always necessary, when you want to say "whatever `this` is".

So, you'd like `this` to stay of type `this`, but the compiler eagerly substitutes `A` for it as soon as you start indexing into it.  The only way to avoid this  is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) on the return value of `items()`.  You'd assert that the return value is of a type that you calculate which depends on `this`:

```
items() {
    return [...this.itemsMap.values()] as
        Array<this["itemsMap"] extends Map<string, infer C> ? C : never>;
}
```

That is using [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) and [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to say "take `this`, look at its `itemsMap` property, figure out what type of values it stores, and return an `Array` of those".  This will now work as you want inside `BColl`:

```
const bColl = new BColl();
bColl.itemsMap.set("foo", new B("foo", "bar"))
console.log(bColl.items()[0].b.toUpperCase()); // BAR
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIWAC4FIoBLAOwHM8CjYB7aigV3magApTzoNWgEpcjIkQgALSmAB0wBAF5iAbnEIAvnm0MUaDACEEAUwAeEE9QAmGbPgkgyFIQwks20ThG59ngugAaBCcBKjpRBwkiMHYABxNeYGF1aMkZeRBlENSibV08UAo4RH10LABhZmRkMQki6BKESksAWzAAWWA4si64gB4XIKwAPjciFpN2nkiNCSgTCHYoagQAbTlN6Vk5Sfa+uQA3YGR2EzAZgF1iMDm0rCgYAE9+7bA1gCI9zu6P6-NLDYMH1BgFaMEaAAzRIICojBAAflhCDI1BMh0SI1yhHyelQ5UMVRqpgsVlslWqtSihG+fV63VB4XBCEM8JUaIA7gg+jMdHpWJAQkTauyTFzCZSZuoQMLdm0fnE5GBFjwPpDmMwPsFOSzVerNcEPiBgFAPsJhHgPGBqiY5MhmLQeDLKXKphdhGsAAyXOQgOQ+ACqcQSUAqaBMMxSCAA9NGWZgAEoMIA)